# How to make Richtextblock scrollable?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">  
<Border Background="AliceBlue">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scroll"                              
                  Height="300"
                  AllowDrop="True"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                  VerticalScrollMode="Auto">

        <RichTextBlock x:Name="richTextBlock"
                       Width="800"
                       Height="400"
                       Margin="50 50 0 0"
                       Foreground="Green">
            <Paragraph x:Name="rchparaGraph">
                <Run />
            </Paragraph>
        </RichTextBlock>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Border>
```

this is how i have align the control. i have used scroll viewer for making rich text block 
scrollable to its content. Its not working. somebody help me.

Comment: *What*'s not working about it?

Answer (score 3):

Remove your ScrollViewer and  Make `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"` inside RichTextBox

```
<RichTextBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
```

**EDIT:**

```
<ScrollViewer Name="scroll"
              Margin="0"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
              Background="#CC000000"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
             <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Margin="0">
             <RichTextBlock x:Name="richTextBlock"
                     Height="100"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center">
             <Paragraph>
                <Run />
             </Paragraph>
        </RichTextBlock>
```

Comment: its not RichTextBox its RichTextBlock.but i did try that but its not still working.

Comment: @user3418509 is it wpf?

Comment: no windows store app. do you have any idea about that?

Comment: @user3418509 Try the modified answer

Comment: its not still working. i want to make only the richTextBlock scrollable.

Comment: Do u have any images in RichTextBlock?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing the StackPanel and replacing it with a Grid. I don't believe that StackPanels and scrolling work well together.